# Is there a way to escape and use reserved words in TypeScript class definitions?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, escaping

Here's a simple example of what I'd like to do:

```
export class UserInfoPrivate {
    constructor(
        public repEmail: string,
        public repPhone: string,
        public agreedToTnC: boolean
    ) { }
}

export class UserInfo {
    constructor(
        public $uid: string,
        public orgApproved: false,
        public private: UserInfoPrivate, // <-- private is a reserved word
        public open: UserInfoOpen,
    ) { }
}
```

Since the datebase is a NoSQL (Firebase) and returns simple JSON structured objects, and I have a node under users called "private" I'd like to just map my class directly to it without extra parsing. Is there a way to use a reserved word such as "private" in a class definition or do I have to go change the node?

My research thus far seems to point to no but I have a hard time accepting that this just isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can always put property names (in classes or object literals) in quotes - and for those that are not valid identifier names, you need to. You can access them using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) then.

```
export class UserInfo {
    public "private": UserInfoPrivate
    constructor(
        public $uid: string,
        public orgApproved: false,
        privateParam: UserInfoPrivate,
        public open: UserInfoOpen,
    ) {
        this.private = privateParam;
    }
}
```

<sub>(I hope that looks like valid Typescript not only to my eye but also the compiler)</sub>

Comment: ...just not where the OP wanted to, in the constructor parameter list (odd omission on TypeScript's part). Also note that while you *can* do `this["private"] = privateParam;` you don't have to; `this.private = privateParam;` is perfectly valid, and has been since ES5 (December 2009).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ah, right. I unnecessarily generalised to strings that are no identifier names at all (e.g. containing spaces). Indeed, `private` is a valid name but not a valid identifier, so we only cannot use it as a variable (or parameter) name.

Comment: @Bergi You can use: `public private: UserInfoPrivate`. It will fail only if you try to use inline with your contructor. Try to remove the `"` from your code and it still working.

Comment: @Diullei Yes, I left that in on purpose to exemplify that you can use quotes when you want

Comment: Thanks for your time but yeah looks like you missed the key problem. When my object comes from the db it has a node called "private" and if I make a property in the constructor of the same name, I can just grab that whole thing and use it as the class and get rich intellisense, etc.... For now my solution has been to change the "private" node to "closed" and now all is well, but it required a lot of refactoring and manual db updating.

Comment: @Methodician My code *does* make a property in the constructor of the name `.private`, doesn't it?

Comment: Interesting maybe it does. At first inspection I assumed no but did not test. Looks like I may have missed the chance to implement your solution. I think it would have still failed on me because the object coming from the db doesn't have a node called "privateParam" but I'm not skilled enough to be sure at a glance. Hopefully I'll get another chance to test it soon. Busy... Good night and thanks for your time. (FWIW I didn't downvote you)

Comment: @Methodician I don't know how your database ORM is calling your constructors, or what "node" means, but function parameter names should not matter.

Comment: In this case I'm mainly using the class as an interface for rich intellisense and preemptive bug detection. When I declare a new object as "UserInfo" and just set it to a raw object out of the database (Firebase is a JSON database) I don't need to call the constructor. If I have the wrong property names then I just get the wrong intellisense. I only call the constructor when I'm creating a new object on the front end to send back to Firebase. If that makes sense... It's all about simplifying the code.

Comment: Yes, but my `class` has a declared `.private` property, so exactly this use case will work. The parameter names of the constructor don't matter.